# Why is Gmail marking my Google Calendar reminders as spam?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, spam-prevention, reminder

Gmail is sending all of my calendar reminders to spam. As far as I can tell, I don't have a filter (or anything else) telling it to do this.

How can I make it stop?  I keep marking everything that it is putting in there as "Not Spam", but all the new reminders are still getting put there.

Comment: It must want you to ignore your appointments and go on vacation!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this has to do with years of the Bayesian filter marking similar keywords as spam.

You can [create a filter](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579) for the email address it comes from (e.g. `calendar-notification@google.com`), then check the **Never send it to Spam** option.

Hopefully after some time, Gmail will learn that these messages should not be sent to spam, and you won't even need this filter. Although, the filter doesn't hurt, so you could leave it there.

Comment: It's particularly strange, because this is a new corporate apps account, so I wouldn't have thought it would have enough time to learn a bad habit like sending it's own reminders to spam

Comment: @Daniel: that is strange

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the Google Calendar logo (the code that inserts the logo) that causes it to be marked as spam in my case. I gradually removed sections of the email and re-sent to myself until the spam flag stopped. It wasn't until I removed the logo I stopped having an issue. Luckily I'm on Google Apps and have control over the filters. Just got to work out which keyword is driving the calculation for the logo insert code to be marking as spam.